# Is it possible to deserialize (from raw memory block) an object with no default constructor?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

I was writing this little tool that helps avoid strict aliasing violations:

```
template <typename TargetType>
TargetType memory_cast(const void* const memoryPtr) noexcept
{
    static_assert(!std::is_reference_v<TargetType>);
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copy_assignable_v<TargetType>);

    TargetType value;
    ::memcpy(&value, memoryPtr, sizeof(value));

    return value;
}
```

And it occurred to me that it will fail if `TargetType` is not default-constructible, but technically speaking that shouldn't matter because we already have a fully constructed data of the object, just no object instance itself to put the data in. Is there a way to solve this problem in modern C++ without invoking UB?

Comment: Do I see this right? You want a copy of the value stored at the pointer address?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: I understand that, but I was hoping there may be a workaround. In olden days we could just cast the memory to object pointer type in order to obtain a structured view of that memory, and it was quite handy and efficient in that it avoid unnecessary construction and `memcopy`.

Comment: @jan.sende: I want to interpret the memory as if it is an instance of some object of type `TargetType`. This is an extremely common task where I/O happens and you want to pass objects around in their raw representation instead of serializing to intermediate formats.

Comment: If you are sure that the memory contains what you think, you can do a reinterpret_cast

Comment: @ArminMontigny: I thought `reinterpret_cast` does not allow bypassing strict aliasing rules, that's the whole problem, the rule prohibits pretty much everything but memcpy.

Comment: @ArminMontigny Not necessarily, in most cases that is incorrect. Only trivially constructible and non-`class` objects can do that, and if you don't have a trivial constructor, you aren't trivially constructible.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: I didn't get your remark on `class` objects since `class` and `struct` is essentially the same in C++, what exactly did you mean? Did you mean built-in types? If a type is POD, what does it matter if it's `class` or not?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe `class` types are types defined by a `struct` or `class` definition. Non-`class` types are all other objects. For example, `int` is a non-`class` type and `int x;` has a non-`class` type.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Sorry, I missed the second part of your comment. Maybe I should have said "Only trivially constructible class types and non-class types". It includes all non-class types (including built-in types) and trivially constructible class types (essentially what you referred to as POD in this context. Note that the concept of POD is deprecated starting in C++20). Those are the types whose lifetime is allowed to begin without a constructor (according to [ccpreference's lifetime page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime)).

Comment: Okay. Then I don't understand what you are trying to do right now. Could you please elaborate in your question... If you want to access the object at the memory location, you should be able to use `reinterpret_cast`, `static_cast`, or the raw pointer... right?

Comment: @jan.sende You'd be violating strict aliasing rules with a cast.

Comment: @iz_ in what context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just pass this problem down to whoever is calling the function:

```cpp
#include <cstring>
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>

template <typename TargetType>
void memory_cast(TargetType& to, const void* const memoryPtr) noexcept
{
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<std::remove_reference_t<TargetType>>);
    std::memcpy(std::addressof(to), memoryPtr, sizeof(to));
}

template <typename TargetType>
TargetType memory_cast(const void* const memoryPtr) noexcept
{
    static_assert(!std::is_reference_v<TargetType>);
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<TargetType>);
    TargetType value;
    memory_cast(value, memoryPtr);

    return value;
}
```

Since the object has to start it's lifetime somewhere, and if it can't be default constructed, there is probably still some way to create it specific to the type (That can be done by the calling code).

[Proposal p0593r2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0593r2.html) would give a new way to do this without breaking strict-aliasing (As `std::memcpy` would now also start the lifetime of an object):

```cpp
template <typename TargetType>
TargetType memory_cast(const void* const memoryPtr) noexcept
{
    static_assert(!std::is_reference_v<TargetType>);
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<TargetType>);
    alignas(TargetType) std::byte value[sizeof(TargetType)];
    std::memcpy(value, memoryPtr, sizeof(TargetType));

    return *reinterpret_cast<TargetType*>(value);
}
```

Comment: I thought of that, just didn't want to settle on it until I made sure there is no better way. Indeed, this is a workable way, too, just not as neat.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Another solution that might look cleaner is passing the constructor arguments to `memory_cast`, like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/gX0XxS)

Comment: I like that a lot, very neat!

Comment: Thanks for the link to P0593.  It looks like R3 of the proposal is here:  http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2019/p0593r3.html

Answer (score 6):

Before [`std::bit_cast` in C++20](https://wg21.link/P0476), it's not really possible to do what you're suggesting, within the confines of the C++ standard. [Trivial copyability](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic#types-2) (not the same thing as `is_trivially_copy_assignable_v`, BTW) permits byte copying between the object representation of live instances of such a type (potentially using an intermediary buffer between them). But you still need a *live instance* to copy into.

Indeed, this is a big part of why `bit_cast` was added to C++20.

Comment: To be more precise, this isn’t possible for the constraints given by OP but if you narrow the constraints (to PODs) it *is* possible. I’m not even sure whether `is_trivial` is necessary (since that’d defeat OP’s stated purpose …).

Comment: Are they making a language change, or is this relying on compiler magic to make it work?

Comment: @NathanOliver: It's not "compiler magic"; it's *fiat*. The standard says that `bit_cast` will do X, and therefore it will do X. The standard library doesn't have to be implementable by other people.

Answer (score 2):

We can add a default parameter that allows us to specify the initial state of the object:

```
template<class TargetType>
constexpr auto get_default = []{ return TargetType{}; };

template <typename TargetType, class Initial = decltype(get_default<TargetType>)>
TargetType memory_cast(
    const void* const memoryPtr,
    Initial initial = get_default<TargetType>) noexcept
{
    static_assert(!std::is_reference_v<TargetType>);
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copy_assignable_v<TargetType>);

    TargetType value = initial();
    ::memcpy(&value, memoryPtr, sizeof(value));

    return value;
}
```

**Handling default-constructible types.** Because the second parameter is defaulted, the interface remains exactly the same:

```
char data[] = "abcd";

int value = memory_cast<int>(data); // default-constructs int, then assigns it from data
```

**Handling types without a default constructor:** Let's say we have a type without a default constructor:

```
struct Foo {
    int x, y, z;
    Foo() = delete;
    Foo(int x, int y, int z) 
      : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}
    Foo(const Foo& foo) = default;
    Foo& operator=(Foo const& foo) = default;
};
```

We can provide the second parameter as a lambda:

```
char data[] = "abcdefghijkl";

Foo f = memory_cast<Foo>(data, []() { return Foo(0, 0, 0); });
```